# SSH with Putty as proxy server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty

I have one restricted network with a Windows machine and one less restricted network with a Linux machine.

I'm only able to initiate connections from the Windows machine to the Linux machine through port 443, using Putty.

My goal is to run ssh (port 22 only) sessions on the Linux machine to hosts in the Windows machine's network using the Windows machine's Putty client as a proxy.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: maybe there is a mess between outgoing and incoming traffic in your question ? Windows port 443 is incoming trafic (https) and Linux port 22 is incoming trafic (ssh), Putty is windows outgoing trafic client ssh, so to connect to Linux check outgoing windows rules and linux incoming rules on the firewall

Comment: Maybe I'm being unclear or I misunderstand your comment. Step 1: connect from Windows host to Linux host using port 443. This step works. Step 2: On the Linux host, connect to a host on the Windows machine's network using port 22. This does not work.

Comment: I'm able to use port 22 internally within the Windows network but not outside.

Comment: so you want putty passing trough windows 443 port then windows transfert trafic to linux port 22 ? look like you have to use NAT on your windows conf (if 443 windows port is not already in use with another service)